# Efficient way to group objects in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting

I have an Array of user defined Objects. Lets say the classy, dogs.
Now I need a way to only look at all brown dogs with spots (both attributes of the Object).

I could create a new array "brown dogs" go through the original array take each dog that has brown fur and pack him in the new array. Then do another array "brown, spotted dogs" and so on you get the idea...
Works but isnt really great.

But I actually need to look at all dogs with each possible color, so all brown dogs in a group, all white dogs etc. And then create further sub groups based on further attributes.

It would be easy in an excel sheet, just filter for brown, and the other attribute, then ran the macro you want, then (by hand) filter to another color, ran code again...

I have a construct in mind that could do that in theory (take value of first attribute, create "already done colors" array, put it in their, go through whole original array, find all with the same color and then do this over and over again for all subsequent attributes) But this would be just very complexe, and hard to maintain. Isnt their an easier and quicker option to only a specific subset of values of the array (brown dogs) and repeat it for all permutations of that attribute?

Maybe this picture helps to illustrate the idea:

[image]

The basic challange is: find if the the combination of b-z (in column 2 and 3) exists for each group of column 1.

A human sees quiet quickly that for group "1" (blue) in column 1 there are 2 cases of b-z (Rows 5 and 7) but none for group "2" (green).

A programm would need to find all instances where column one is of the first value ("2") and then find all other rows with this value (rows 2,5 and 6) then for this list check column 2 and 3.

Go to the next row and check if attribute 1 was already used (it wasnt, its "1" in line two and was "2" in line one) and then compare again.

This may be doable for the given example but gets burdensome when you have several stages of grouping. So first group for Attribute one, then for ( a hyphotetical) attribute 4 and attribute 5 and then for this sub group check columns 2 an d 3 values.

Iam now looking for a way to do this "grouping" in a more managable way, is there any option for this?

Code example for what I think is a not so great version for grouping/filtering this:

```
dim ArrayofObjectInstances() as SpecificObject
dim ArrAlreadyUsedIds() as integer
dim ArrayOfObjectsWithSameID() as SpecificObject

For each element in ArrayofObjectInstances
If not IsinArray(elemnt.ID, ArrAlreadyUsedIds) then

For i = 1 to LenghtOfArray
if ArrayofObjectInstances(i).ID Like element.ID then
'In here I would start the for each and the for loop again for a second Attribute I want to group by, and then again for a third, each time needing more arrays


'fill the "ArrayOfObjectsWithSameID" with the current element (and the first one), then lopp through this array and check 2 Attributes if they are spevific values, 
'just to then be able to say, yes the grouping for this ID has at least one instance where the reuirment is meet
end if
next

end if
next element
```

Comment: You ask for a `... more manageable way` but don't provide a baseline. Do you have an existing implementation of the class and a method of filtering a collection of instances of that class ?

Comment: I have the class off course or better the array of instances of the class but so far I havent implemented a filtering/grouping method since the only one that comes to my mind (described in the question) doesnt seem like a particularly good way to do it. In this case It feels kinda contra productiv to code this version, just to provide an example of a lengthy/complex, slowly working version when a better idea probbly is already on somebodys mind.

Comment: So, should we understand that in your graphic presentation the first column is not an attribute, most probably the entity you named as a 'group'? And you need to identify groups according to their attribute membership for a specific interval?

Comment: Do you have an existing attributes array?

Comment: Almost the first column is an attribute and in reality is an ID like "ABC123". Now each Instance of the object that has this ID needs to be grouped by 2 further IDs and then this subgroup need to be checked if any of them have a certain value as (yet another) attribute. So 3 IDs to group by, then check if another Attribute is XYZ and if thats the case for one of the attributes in the subgroup the whole subgroup gets its another Attribute(Flag) set to true... thats the full picture ^^

Comment: I would suggest a different approach... So, you can use Scripting Dictionary. Then iterate between all existing instances, use the instance atribute as dictionary (unique) key and fill the item with an array to keep all instances of the same attribute. This should be easy and creating it should take less than a second for a big range. Than, having all instances using a specific attribute to deal with querying should be simpler.

Comment: Thanks sounds good, can you give me a quick code example as an answer, I have never worked with Scripting Dictornarys before.

Comment: OK. I will try imagining a piece of code starting from your above picture. I will consider the first column the objects (even if strings), and the other columns keeping attributes. The attributes could be in the same column, for the code to be faster. That's why I was asking for a attributes array.

Comment: "A human sees quiet quickly" and "A programm would need to find" describe the same process though?  No offense intended, but your question seems kind of vague - it mentions needing to slice and dice your array into different subgroups, but doesn't describe what process is going to provide the necessary inputs to *control* that aggregation.  "How to aggregate objects based on distinct property combinations" seems quite open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go:

Test class `clsTest`:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Id As Long
Public Color As String
Public Weight As String
Public Attitude As String

'added this for Debug output
Public Property Get AsString()
    AsString = Join(Array(Me.Id, Me.Color, Me.Weight, Me.Attitude), "~")
End Property
```

Test code:

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub Tester()

    Dim i As Long, obj As clsTest, col As New Collection
    
    'create a collection of test objects with randomized property values
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set obj = New clsTest
        obj.Id = i
        obj.Color = Array("Blue", "Brown", "Yellow") _
                         (Application.RandBetween(0, 2))
        obj.Weight = Array("Heavy", "Light")(Application.RandBetween(0, 1))
        
        obj.Attitude = Array("Good", "Bad")(Application.RandBetween(0, 1))
        
        col.Add obj
    Next i
    
    DumpNestedDict Classify(col, Array("Color"))
    
    DumpNestedDict Classify(col, Array("Color", "Weight"))
    
    DumpNestedDict Classify(col, Array("Weight", "Color", "Attitude"))
    
End Sub

'Classify a collection of objects according to an array of property names
'Returns a scripting dictionary (nested if >1 property) with objects
'   contained in one or more collections 
Function Classify(col, arrProps)
    
    Dim dict As Object, pv, i As Long, curr As Object, obj As Object
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    For Each obj In col
        Set curr = dict 'start at the top level...
        For i = LBound(arrProps) To UBound(arrProps)
            pv = CallByName(obj, arrProps(i), VbGet) 'get the property value
            If Not curr.exists(pv) Then
                If i < UBound(arrProps) Then 'at the last property?
                    'not at last property, so create a nested dictionary
                    curr.Add pv, CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
                Else
                    'end of the road is a collection of objects
                    curr.Add pv, New Collection 'end of the road is a collection of objects
                End If
            End If
            If i < UBound(arrProps) Then Set curr = curr(pv) 'one level down in the nesting
            
            'last property, so add the object itself
            If i = UBound(arrProps) Then
                curr(pv).Add obj
            End If
        Next i
    Next obj
    
    Set Classify = dict
End Function

'create a text output from a nested dictionary containing collections of objects
'  object must have an "AsString" property
Sub DumpNestedDict(d As Object, Optional level As Long = 0)
    Dim k, v, s, obj
    s = String(level * 3, " ")
    For Each k In d.Keys
        Debug.Print s & "Key:" & k
        If TypeName(d(k)) = "Dictionary" Then
            DumpNestedDict d(k), level + 1
        ElseIf TypeName(d(k)) = "Collection" Then
            For Each obj In d(k)
                Debug.Print String((level + 1) * 3, " ") & obj.AsString
            Next obj
        End If
    Next k
    If level = 0 Then Debug.Print "---------------------------", vbLf
End Sub
```

Example output:

```txt
Key:Yellow
   1~Yellow~Light~Good
   3~Yellow~Light~Bad
   4~Yellow~Heavy~Good
   6~Yellow~Light~Bad
   10~Yellow~Heavy~Good
Key:Brown
   2~Brown~Light~Bad
   7~Brown~Heavy~Bad
   8~Brown~Heavy~Bad
Key:Blue
   5~Blue~Heavy~Bad
   9~Blue~Light~Good
--------------------------- 

Key:Yellow
   Key:Light
      1~Yellow~Light~Good
      3~Yellow~Light~Bad
      6~Yellow~Light~Bad
   Key:Heavy
      4~Yellow~Heavy~Good
      10~Yellow~Heavy~Good
Key:Brown
   Key:Light
      2~Brown~Light~Bad
   Key:Heavy
      7~Brown~Heavy~Bad
      8~Brown~Heavy~Bad
Key:Blue
   Key:Heavy
      5~Blue~Heavy~Bad
   Key:Light
      9~Blue~Light~Good
--------------------------- 

Key:Light
   Key:Yellow
      Key:Good
         1~Yellow~Light~Good
      Key:Bad
         3~Yellow~Light~Bad
         6~Yellow~Light~Bad
   Key:Brown
      Key:Bad
         2~Brown~Light~Bad
   Key:Blue
      Key:Good
         9~Blue~Light~Good
Key:Heavy
   Key:Yellow
      Key:Good
         4~Yellow~Heavy~Good
         10~Yellow~Heavy~Good
   Key:Blue
      Key:Bad
         5~Blue~Heavy~Bad
   Key:Brown
      Key:Bad
         7~Brown~Heavy~Bad
         8~Brown~Heavy~Bad
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, test the next code. I tried commenting it in a way to be understandable for somebody not familiar with dictionaries handling:

```
Sub testDictionariyWay()
 'it needs a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime'
 'The code may use late binding, but not being experienced in dictionary using, adding this reference
 'you will have access to intellisense suggestions. I will also place a piece of code able to put it automatically...
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, arrOb, dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, boolExisting As Boolean
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("A2:C7").value      'put the range to be processed in an array (only to make the code faster and more compact)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then 'if the attribute does not exist like a dictionary key:
        dict.Add arr(i, 2), Array(arr(i, 1))            'a key is created and an array of one element is placed like its value
    Else
       ReDim arrOb(UBound(dict(arr(i, 2))) + 1) 'redim an array able to keep all precedent array elements, plus one to be added
       For j = 0 To UBound(arrOb) - 1              'iterate between the existing array elements:
            If dict(arr(i, 2))(j) <> arr(i, 1) Then    'check if the object is not already in the array:
                arrOb(j) = dict(arr(i, 2))(j)            'if not, it will be placed in the new array
            Else
                boolExisting = True: Exit For         'if the object already exists, the loop is exited and a boolean variable becomes True
            End If
       Next j
       If Not boolExisting Then                        'if not the object already exist:
            arrOb(j) = arr(i, 1)                           'place the new object in the last array element
            dict(arr(i, 2)) = arrOb                       'add the array as dictionary key value
       End If
       boolExisting = False                              'reinitialize he boolean variable
    End If
    'do the same for the third column:
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 3)) Then
        dict.Add arr(i, 3), Array(arr(i, 1))
    Else
       ReDim arrOb(UBound(dict(arr(i, 3))) + 1)
       For j = 0 To UBound(arrOb) - 1
            If dict(arr(i, 3))(j) <> arr(i, 1) Then
                arrOb(j) = dict(arr(i, 3))(j)
            Else
                boolExisting = True: Exit For
            End If
       Next j
       If Not boolExisting Then
            arrOb(j) = arr(i, 1)
            dict(arr(i, 3)) = arrOb
       End If
       boolExisting = False
    End If
 Next i
'testing the dictionary content. Now, being a strings array, Debug.Print can be used.
'Otherwise, an object will be returned and it should be Set and use one of its attributes to check the code:
 Dim El As Variant
 For Each El In dict("a")
    Debug.Print "a: " & El
 Next El
 For Each El In dict("x")
    Debug.Print "x: " & El
 Next El
End Sub
```

The next piece of code will automatically add the necessary reference. Please, first run the following code, save the workbook (to keep the reference) and then run the above one:

```
Sub addScrRunTimeRef()
  'Add a reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime':
  'In case of error ('Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project not trusted'):
  'Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings->Macro Settings->Developer Macro Settings->
  '         check "Trust access to the VBA project object model"
  Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"
End Sub
```

**Edited** to add a variant involving a class and its instances, to be more elocvent (at least, this is what I hope):

1. Create a class module, named 'clsFoo' and paste the next code:

```
Option Explicit

Private pmyName As String
Private pmyColor As String
Private pmyTag As String 'to identify the class Object instance (string) name...

Public Property Get myName() As String
    myName = pmyName
End Property
Public Property Let myName(value As String)
    pmyName = value
End Property
Public Property Get myColor() As String
    myColor = pmyColor
End Property
Public Property Let myColor(value As String)
    pmyColor = value
End Property
Public Property Get myTag() As String
    myTag = pmyTag
End Property
Public Property Let myTag(value As String)
    pmyTag = value
End Property
```

2. Try the next code showing how to create dictionaries for both class properties:

```
Sub testClassInstancesInDict()
  Dim arrFoo(4), Foo1 As New clsFoo, Foo2 As New clsFoo, Foo3 As New clsFoo, Foo4 As New clsFoo, Foo5 As New clsFoo
  Dim El As Variant, dictName As New Scripting.Dictionary, dictColor As New Scripting.Dictionary, arrClss() As clsFoo, i As Long
  
  Foo1.myName = "Name1": Foo1.myColor = "red": Foo1.myTag = "Foo1": Set arrFoo(0) = Foo1
  Foo2.myName = "Name2": Foo2.myColor = "black": Foo2.myTag = "Foo2": Set arrFoo(1) = Foo2
  Foo3.myName = "Name1": Foo3.myColor = "green": Foo3.myTag = "Foo3": Set arrFoo(2) = Foo3
  Foo4.myName = "Name4": Foo4.myColor = "black": Foo4.myTag = "Foo4": Set arrFoo(3) = Foo4
  Foo5.myName = "Name1": Foo5.myColor = "white": Foo5.myTag = "Foo5": Set arrFoo(4) = Foo5
  For Each El In arrFoo
    'process dictName dictionary:
    If Not dictName.Exists(El.myName) Then
        dictName.Add El.myName, Array(El)
    Else
        ReDim arrClss(UBound(dictName(El.myName)) + 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(dictName(El.myName))
            Set arrClss(i) = dictName(El.myName)(i)
        Next i
        Set arrClss(i) = El: dictName(El.myName) = arrClss
    End If
    'process dictColor dictionary:
    If Not dictColor.Exists(El.myColor) Then
        dictColor.Add El.myColor, Array(El)
    Else
        ReDim arrClss(UBound(dictColor(El.myColor)) + 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(dictColor(El.myColor))
            Set arrClss(i) = dictColor(El.myColor)(i)
        Next i
        Set arrClss(i) = El: dictColor(El.myColor) = arrClss
    End If
  Next
  
  'test the resulted dictionaries:
  Debug.Print "DictName Name1 key has " & UBound(dictName("Name1")) & " clsFoo objects"
  Debug.Print "DictColor black key has " & UBound(dictColor("black")) & " clsFoo objects"
  Dim j As Long
  
  'all dictName keys/items. myTag returns the object string name:
  Debug.Print "dictName _________________________"
  For j = 0 To dictName.count - 1
        For i = 0 To UBound(dictName.items(j))
            Debug.Print "KeyName: " & dictName.Keys(j) & vbTab & dictName.items(j)(i).myName & _
                             vbTab & dictName.items(j)(i).myColor & vbTab & dictName.items(j)(i).myTag
        Next i
  Next
  
  'all dictColor keys/items:
  Debug.Print: Debug.Print "dictColor ________________________"
  For j = 0 To dictColor.count - 1
        For i = 0 To UBound(dictColor.items(j))
            Debug.Print "KeyColor: " & dictColor.Keys(j) & vbTab & dictColor.items(j)(i).myName & _
                          vbTab & dictColor.items(j)(i).myColor & vbTab & dictColor.items(j)(i).myTag
        Next i
  Next
End Sub
```